# Why for boundary analysis, the least unit should be specified?

Tags: testing, boundary

The book Guide to advanced software testing mentiones that the smallest increment for BVA should always be known.

But I do not see why:

10 - 20 Boundary values 9,10 and 20,21.

10.0 - 20.0 Boundary values 9.9,10.0 and 20.0,20.1

I mean if there is a fault caused by e.g. missing = or incorrect relation operator, it does not matter whether the value is larger by 1 or 0.1. What is the point of knowing the least possible unit, could you provide me an example where it actually matters?

Answer (score 0):

You have a machine in a hospital measuring temperature. The machine should alert the doctor if the temperature exceeds 98.6 degrees for longer than 10 minutes. You check for 98, 98.6, 99. The person's temperature stays at 98.9 for a few hours. Is this a problem? No idea! I'm not a doctor!

A better question may be why would you not be as precise as possible. If the requirement states >60, and you are allowed 2 decimal places, why would you test 61 instead of 60.01?

The fault does not necessarily lie in the operator. There could be a rounding or truncation problem somewhere. Go ask any accountant what the significance is between $1.00 and $1.10 across a few hundred million transactions a day.

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between 1 and 0.1: your first case shows whole number while second case shows fractional.

So if you test 10-20 range with value of 9.9 you may get error of data type (fractional instead of whole, or float instead of byte). By doing that, instead of testing range you test data type. This test is also important but different from the boundary analysis.